# Call completionHandler when two API calls have both completed?

Tags: ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

In the `init` method of a class I’m triggering two API calls which respond via delegate. The class itself needs to send a completion handler when both of the two calls have returned their data. I’ve tried using GCD and a dispatch group to accomplish this, but I’m not entirely sure where in the code I need to put the `notify` part. The delegate method (`didReceiveData` is called twice, once for each call), could be in any order, etc., basically I need a means of knowing when both of them finished, and returning both of their sets of data in a single completionHandler.

I’m a little stumped as to where to begin, I’ve done some looking around and I can’t quite get the GCD or `NSOperation` methods working. The instance is sticking around long enough for the two calls to come back, but since they come back at almost the same time, they can’t check to see whether the other has finished. I’m not sure how to check, and I’m not sure WHERE to check, either.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished this using NSNotifications.  Basically, when each API request completes, post a NSNotification.  Add a NSNotification listener to manage the state of tracking when each notification is fired.  Once the listener has received both notifications, then the completionHandler may be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set a counter (integer property or a static integer value in the calling method) to the class calling these two API requests and then do whatever the return block is supposed to do only if the counter has a certain value else increase/decrease the counter and wait for the other response. That is a bad procedure but it is with least effort.

If you want to do this the right way there are quite a few ways:

- You can create a class that specifically handles these 2 requests and includes both of the responses as a property for instance. Then in response block you set the target response property and check if the other response is already set, if so you call the input block.
- You can create a class that receives an array of requests and a callback block then you either use an internal counter or simply save the responses. Then you count the response count on every response received and see if you have enough to call an input callback block.
- You can create a system through blocks where you pass in a mutable dictionary where each block should set a specific key (with the response object or status code or whatever) and on each callback then check if you have enough objects in the dictionary to continue the process.

There are so many possibilities on this... I would always suggest to try make it so you have at least code in the class that calls this set of requests as possible and the first procedure would do exactly that. But then again if you have many cases where you call a different set of the requests then it is better to create a more general system such as mentioned in second and third procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this without `delegates` so idk how you feel about that, but this does work. I did have to tweak the code a bit so there might be an error or two because maybe some variables don't exists because I deleted them for this answer.

**CLASS API**

API.h

`-(void)getMyDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *firstData, NSMutableArray *secondData))Final_callBack;`

API.m

```
-(void)getMyDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *firstData, NSMutableArray *secondData))Final_callBack {

    NSString *firstURL = @"www.firstURL.com";
    NSString *secondURL = @"www.secondURL.com";

    __block bool firstIsBack = false;
    __block bool secondIsBack = false;

    __block NSMutableArray *firstArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    __block NSMutableArray *secondArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self getFirstData:firstURL
             withCallBack:^(NSMutableArray *firstData) {
              firstIsBack = true;
              firstArray = firstData;
                if (firstIsBack && secondIsBack){
                        Final_callBack(firstArray,secondArray);
                }      
                    
              }
    }];

    [self getSecondData:secondURL
             withCallBack:^(NSMutableArray *secondData) {
              secondIsBack = true;
              secondArray = secondData;
                if (firstIsBack && secondIsBack){
                  Final_callBack(firstArray,secondArray);
                }      
                    
              }
    }];    
}
```

**VIEWCONTROLLER**

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *finalFirstArray; @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *finalSecondArray;`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    API *myApi = [API new];
    //make first call to 
    [myApi getMyDataWithCompletionHandler:^(NSMutableArray *firstData, NSMutableArray *secondData) {
         _finalFirstArray = firstData;
         _finalSecondArray = secondData;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a dispatch group, each call need only worry about its own completion. The general idea is as follows:

**Init method**: Start with an empty dispatch group (newly-created, or which has balanced calls to `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave`). Before making each API call, call `dispatch_group_enter`. Once you've made all your API calls, call `dispatch_group_notify` with your completion handler.

**Delegate method**: Call `dispatch_group_leave` on the dispatch group. How you provide the dispatch group to your delegate is largely up to how your code works.

The block you passed to `dispatch_group_notify` will only be enqueued to the target queue once the number of calls to `dispatch_group_enter` is equal to the number of calls to `dispatch_group_leave`. You have already made one call to `dispatch_group_enter` for each request at the time that you called `dispatch_group_notify`, so you need one `dispatch_group_leave` for each request, which will be triggered when the requests return their data. Note that the dispatch group doesn't care about the order in which your requests return, since all it sees are calls to `dispatch_group_leave` with no additional arguments.